# How to find which IP address is active for communication?

Tags: powershell, ip-address, powershell-2.0

I am using Windows XP Sp3. We are having both wired network and wireless network.

Both will have different IP address range .

Is there any way to find which IP address/Gateway is used to communicate?

i.e. We are having permission to wired network IP range to rdp to our lab machines. But with wireless connection we can't.

Often people forget that and asking me.

If the wireless network is active channel , then it should either try to connect through wired network or it should intimate them. How to achieve this using powershell?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the same information `route print` shows like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | select Destination, Mask, NextHop, Metric1
```

If your network address is 10.0.0.0 you can get the NextHop IP like this:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_IP4RouteTable | ? {$_.Destination -eq "10.0.0.0"} | select NextHop
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you should manually add routes to lab machines for wired interface. And you could detemine current route settings with command:

```
route print
```

running from windows console (cmd )

Guess this links could be also helpfull to you:

[Configure default gateway](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ras_config_incoming_tcpip_defaultgw.mspx?mfr=true)

[Usage route command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true)

[Adding static IP route](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx)